# Visual C# Express - How to spell check comments in a whole project?

Tags: c#, spell-checking, visual-c#-express-2010

I need to spell check all comments in my project. Any easy way to do that?

Note that I am using Visual C# Express (free) and not Visual Studio (paid).

Or is there any other external program I can use (real time)?

Thanks

Comment: The spelling of comments is not that vital, it's the content of them

Comment: Express won't allow add-ins so you'll need a separate tool. And would you really trust any spellchecker to replace/fix text?

Comment: @Oskar: I disagree with that, especially on international projects.

Comment: Oskar: It's more professional to have comments spell checked. It's 2010, yes.

Henk: Ideally it would be an real-time spell checker (like the one Eclipse has) and I would fix the words manually.

Comment: @jv42 Don't get me wrong, I'm pro writing correct comments and I think it's really important with correct grammar and spelling. But it isn't by any means vital

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[SCSC](http://www.parasitesoft.com/scsc.html) seems to be an external tool that says that it supports spell checking C# comments.

Answer (score 0):

You need a plugin if you want this in Visual Studio. Check out [this link](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/7c8341f1-ebac-40c8-92c2-476db8d523ce/). However, I don't believe you can use plugins in Visual C# Express.